# How to access variable tags in golang?

Tags: go, tags, field

I'm curious on how to access variable tags in golang. I know JSON uses them like this:

```
type Foo struct {
    Bar string `json:"-"`
}
```

But I can't seem to find a way to access those tags in code for my own use. How can I get those values so I can use them in code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would use reflection. See [this](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#example_StructTag) example from the go docs:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    type S struct {
        F string `species:"gopher" color:"blue"`
    }

    s := S{}
    st := reflect.TypeOf(s)
    field := st.Field(0)
    fmt.Println(field.Tag.Get("color"), field.Tag.Get("species"))

}
```